# Office 2013 default IMAP folder mapping

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm using Outlook 2013 with a standard IMAP Server without XLIST support. As far as I can tell, it's not possible any more to configure the IMAP folder mapping in Outlook 2013. What default folder names dose Office 2013 map the Drafts, Trash, Sent folders to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Outlook 2013 did not map the correct folders of my IMAP account, I manually renamed the special folders on the server to:

- INBOX
- Sent Items
- Deleted Items
- Drafts
- Spam

I deleted the wrong folders on the server which Outlook had newly created.

I stopped Outlook and deleted the .ost file of this account to force Outlook to map the folders again. On restart, Outlook mapped the folders correctly.